# Error with "partial" function in pdp package when using random forest

Tags: r, random-forest, partial

I am getting an error message when using the `partial` function from the `pdp` package on my random forest model. I am trying to plot a partial dependence plot using this package.

```
library(randomForest)
library(pdp)

# random forest model
set.seed(101)
model_rf <- randomForest(Rec ~ ., data = sample, importance = TRUE)

# from pdp package
p1 <- partial(model_rf, pred.var = "HDI", plot = TRUE)
```

Then I get this error when running into the last line:

> Error: `.f` must be a function, not a a
>   `randomForest.formula/randomForest` object

I'm not sure what `.f` its referring to and I have found the exact same code online where this `partial` function works using a random forest model.

Comment: Hey julia, have you checked if model_rf is actually a model? like summary(model) should help you confirm that

Answer (score 5):

The same problem bothered me as well. I will post the solution here, so that people can learn from my mistake.

I had the same error when using pdp because I also loaded the dplyr package, which resulted in pdp::partial being blocked due to name conflict. Check the conflicts and detach the package with "conflicting interest", then it should be all good.

Answer (score 0):

pdp::partial(model_rf, pred.var = "HDI", plot = TRUE)
this may help

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).